# How can i get data row by row in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

This is my 1 example data. There are 15 of these data.
How can i get 
**4** (data-class), 
**8,2**(data-score),
**Parkk**(name)
I want data row by row. I think i must use foreach, someone can help me ?

```
<div class="sr_item sr_item_new      sr_item_default                sr_property_block  sr_flex_layout         card-bigger-price      sr_item--with-value-deal    "
        data-hotelid="10274"
        data-class="4"
        data-score="8,2"
        data-recommended="1"
        data-row-number="1">
        <a class="hotel_name_link url"
        href="/hotel/nl/parkhoteladam.tr.html?aid=309654;label=booking-be-tr-JKGYPlETyQ8zXLSF_YGpswS70199808652%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap2%3Aac%3Aap1t1%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atikwd-21085524309%3Alp1012783%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm;sid=8b79e4c094eb1d07801d638dbebd5d45;dcid=4;checkin=2015-11-28;checkout=2015-11-29;ucfs=1;room1=A,A;srfid=ddba57556d198f7f351dfd7936afdee5e7b5d96fX1;highlight_room="
         target="_blank" 
        data-component="track" data-track="mouseenter" data-stage="1" data-hash="HMDCcKPRNHcXJEbSaTfRe"
        >
        Parkk
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'sr_item sr_item_new') and contains(@class, 'sr_item_default') and contains(@class, 'sr_property_block') and contains(@class, 'sr_flex_layout')and contains(@class, 'card-bigger-price')and contains(@class, 'sr_item--with-value-deal')]");
string hotelID = div.GetAttributeValue("data-hotelid", "");
string dataClass = div.GetAttributeValue("data-class", "");
string dataScore = div.GetAttributeValue("data-score", "");
string dataRecommended = div.GetAttributeValue("data-recommended", "");
string name = div.InnerText.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957071/1940851).
The xpath used to get the divs starts with "//div" which means that it will find all the dics that meet the criteria. The foreach loop then extracts the data from each div. You still have to populate that data into a list of a class.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc.Load(link);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'sr_item sr_item_new') and contains(@class, 'sr_item_default') and contains(@class, 'sr_property_block') and contains(@class, 'sr_flex_layout')and contains(@class, 'card-bigger-price')and contains(@class, 'sr_item--with-value-deal')]");
        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode n in divs)
        {
            string hotelID = n.GetAttributeValue("data-hotelid", "");
            string dataClass = n.GetAttributeValue("data-class", "");
            string dataScore = n.GetAttributeValue("data-score", "");
            string dataRecommended = n.GetAttributeValue("data-recommended", "");
            string name = n.SelectSingleNode("a").InnerText;
        }
    }
```